# Should co-workers be added as contacts in whattsapp?

Tags: colleagues

This question might sound sort of familiar as: *Should we maintain the difference between personal and professional contacts?* but is not.

**Background:**

- As a new employee I am added to the whattsapp group.
- Only my contacts can see my picture.
- I started adding some of them as contacts.
- I did a public approach (meaning all the group could hear) to a specific co-worker stating I didn't see his picture and hence which one was him.
- Other member stated he didn't have co-workers added as contacts.

**Thoughts:**

- Numbers appear in the chat group if anytime I need to contact them.
- I want to be trusted, of course there are other means, obviously, but seen in a picture says a lot in this context.
- Some of them have public pictures, others have started adding me.

This is strictly related to whattsapp contacts.

- Should I add them so they can see my picture? Yes or No and why.
- Any other approaches or solutions? Yes or No and which.

Comment: What makes you think there's a set answer to this? You may as well ask "Who should I add on Facebook" really. Perhaps a more useful question would be: "*What should I consider before adding someone?*" but then again I don't think adding someone actually does anything...

Comment: Does it worry you that they see your picture?

Comment: Don't overthink...

Comment: Do you work permanently from a remote location? If not, what's the problem with them seeing your picture, when they can see your face all the time?  Or perhaps you use some "interesting" picture instead of your photo?

Answer (score 5):

You should ask yourself an important question before you invite your colleagues to be part of your personal social media network. The question is

**Am I completely certain that I will never post anything on my social media that I wouldn't want my work colleagues to see?**

If the answer is not a hearty Yes, then don't invite your work colleagues to your network. Make a separate network for them (like LinkedIn) or create a separate account for them.

Remember that 'things I don't want my colleagues to see' includes not just 'My stupid boss made me do pointless extra work today' (check out the people fired for posting that) but also 'I'm going to this political meeting that not everyone might agree with' or 'I was really wasted last night'.

Answer (score 1):

Unless there's an official company mandate to use Whattsapp (or any other social media system) then it's entirely your decision whether or not to add co-workers to your contact list.

In the past, when I've found myself needing a Google Account (in my case) for work purposes, I just created a new account using my corporate email address, which I then used for all company purposes.  I kept my personal Google account separate.  No one complained, or probably even noticed.

Answer (score 0):

whatsapp i suggest you get another number because when you use your personal ,there is a chance you ll meet your colleague in facebook ,since whatsapp has relation with facebook ,this i can 100% guarantee because i face this before .Your colleague may not be happy and could runied your reputation ,and when you want to leave your job ,your letter wont be nice about it especially your boss